# Clear sessionStorage when user navigates away?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have `sessionStorage.setItem` that triggers when someone clicks a button.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('save', saved);
```

That's nice, but is there a way with jQuery to delete this `sessionStorage` upon user navigating away from the page in any way?

The answer I found so far. . .

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
    $.ajax("someURL", {
        async: false,
        data: "test",
        success: function(event) {
             console.log("Ajax request executed");
        }
    });
    return "This is a jQuery version";
});
```

. . . had way complicated-seeming AJAX.

But I am finding some simpler way to do this?

Comment: What does "navigate away" mean exactly? Do you want to detect when all tabs from site are closed? Why is it an issue if data persists until the browser closes? How can you even remove sessionStorage using AJAX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you need AJAX?
Just use `beforeunload` event and clear `sessionStorage` item?

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
sessionStorage.removeItem('save'); 
});
```

Comment: It's hard to say if this solves anything given that the question is IMHO pretty vague. Using `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` implies sharing data between pages. Removing on page unload defeats that purpose.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I Agree with you, but maybe he wants to add this script on certain conditions, actions or pages. The purpose was not the question, it was how to. And if I am not mistaken, this does answer it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález `beforeunload` reacts to page, `sessionStorage` to browser tab. So I can see how this my work, even if logic behind mind be a bit wrong. Hard to say as you said it.